# Loop through array of images as a Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, animation, carousel

I'm trying to create a multi-item carousel, in pure JavaScript, using zero carousel plugins.

I want to achieve is having a div, which contains 4/5 images. Sitting next to each other. And then when you click a "next" or "prev" button, you can scroll through the images carousel

Here's a codepen so far:
https://codepen.io/ReenaVerma1981/pen/KKKZoYV

- My approach is to have an array of images.
- Loop through them to display them, side by side in the div.
- And then onClick of a next button, loop through the display of images, as a carousel event further.
- Even when you get to the list image, ensure the carousel continues to work, by looping from the first image in the array again.

I'm getting stuck on the last part. I'm not sure, how to loop through my carousel of images.

**So far I have just displayed them statically.  You can see I am already looping through my array and display each image, in an individual div. In a container carousel div.**

```js
    const arrayCarousel = ['https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/200', 
    'https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200', 
    'https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200', 
    'https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/200', 
    'https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100'];

    
     for (let i = 0; i < arrayCarousel.length; i++) {
      const imageURL = arrayCarousel[i];
      console.log('imageURL', imageURL);

      const divElement = document.createElement("div");
      const imgElement = document.createElement("img");
      imgElement.src = imageURL;

      divElement.classList.add("item");
      divElement.appendChild(imgElement);
      carouselContainer.appendChild(divElement);
    }
```

```html
 <section>
        <div class="carousel-container" id="carousel-container">
        </div>
 </section>
```

**Not sure on how to progress with the next part.... dynamically, scrolling through my array of images.**

Any tips on how to create a multi-item carousel, using an array of images?

Thanks!

Comment: You can go through the index file on https://github.com/kalesh13/z-Carousel This is something I built for showing testimonials. It uses Animate.css. Take a look if it's of any help.

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan - Thank you, but this is a package/plugin right??  I'm looking to write this from scratch!! thank you!

Comment: Yeah. You can refer the code to see if it is of any help. Its just single index.js file. By the way, I just read your comment on the answer and it looks like I misunderstood your requirement at first. The one you are asking for would require an additional `div` element in the end with all the images stacked and 2 buttons to navigate around the images individually. These two buttons click event can be hooked to do the necessary navigation, probably css class add/delete to highlight the selected image.

Comment: I know that.  My question was around the logic, to loop through the array, and the images/move change, on click.

Comment: Do you have any fiddle that we can look at? To be honest, your requirement is still unclear.

Comment: Sure @KaleshKaladharan - here's a code pen:https://codepen.io/ReenaVerma1981/pen/KKKZoYV

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201766/discussion-between-kalesh-kaladharan-and-reena-verma).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something I quickly came up with. Might not be a copy paste solution. Just sharing general idea of how you can do it.

Zoom animations should work fine. Slide animation would require working with DOM elements instead of swapping the images

```
/**
 * Deregisters the carousal when either next or previous
 * button is clicked. On button clicks, deregister and 
 * re-register is required to avoid image change collisions.
 * 
 * Callback is executed which changes the order of images
 * array.
 * 
 * setItem is called to apply the image order changes.
 * 
 * registerCarousal registers a new carousal loop, so that the
 * loop continues forever.
 */
function onButtonClick(callback) {
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') return;

    deregisterCarousel();
    callback();
    setItem();
    registerCarousal();
}

/**
 * Responsible for changing the src on the
 * carousalItems.
 */
function setItem() {
    var img = document.getElementsByClassName('carousalItems');

    for (let i = 0; i < img.length; li++) {
        img.src = images[i];
    }
}

/**
 * Removes the first image and pushes it to the
 * end of the array.
 */
function shiftForNext() {
    let firstItem = images.shift();
    images.push(firstItem);
}

/**
 * Deregisters the existing timer.
 */
function deregisterCarousel() {

    if (timer == null) return;

    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null;
}

function registerCarousal() {
    // Remove any existing timer.
    deregisterCarousel();

    // Loop every 1.5 seconds and shifts the 
    // images from 0 to length direction.
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        shiftForNext();

        // Responsible for changing the image src
        // on carousal list elements.
        setItem();
    }, 1500);
}

let timer = null;

let images = [
    'https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/200',
    'https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200',
    'https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200',
    'https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/200',
    'https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100',
    'https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100',
    'https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100',
];

// Registers the next button click.
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function () {
    onButtonClick(function () {
        shiftForNext();
    });
});

// Registers the previous button click.
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', function () {
    onButtonClick(function () {
        // Removes the last element of the images array
        let lastItem = images.pop();

        // And pushes it to the first position.
        images.unshift(lastItem);
    });
});

// Registers the carousal
registerCarousal();
```

Comment: Thank you @kalesh - I will play around with this. It looks really clean, logical and concise.  I've actually come up with a basic solution myself, which works too.  But I will try you solution as well. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [setInterval method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and loop through your image array:

```js
const arrayCarousel = ['https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/200', 
'https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200', 
'https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/200', 
'https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100'];

counter = 0
const setImage = () => {
 document.getElementById("carousel-image").src = arrayCarousel[counter];
 counter = (counter+1)  % arrayCarousel.length;
}

setInterval(setImage, 1000);
```

```html
  <section>

    <img id="carousel-image" >

  </section>
```

Comment: Aaah sorry I wasn't clear.... I'd trying to have all the images display in the carouse/div at once, which they do.  EG Image 1, Image 2, Image 3, Image 4 all appear in the div next to each other.

And then clicking on "next" or a "prev" button, allows you to scroll further through the images/array, which have been injected into the div.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought you wanted a JS solution. Because aligning all images would require some css.

Comment: Yes I'll be using CSS as well for an animation. But what i meant is I don't want to use an out of box carousel plugin.  I want to write this in vanilla JS.